rysnc when filenames have been changed identically on both ends
I have an external hard disk which I back up to another external hard disk using rsync.
I have recently changed a large number of the filenames on the primary hard disk to match a new format.
If I make the same filename changes directly on the backup disk (which I would do with a script), how will rsync proceed? Ideally I'd like it not to re-copy those files, as it's probably over a terabyte of files that have received new filenames.
I'm guessing that making the same filename changes directly on the backup disk is the best way to go, but if there are alternatives I'd also like to hear about them.

There are basically no better alternatives to renaming the files.

How does rsync cope with it? Does it have any issues because the last modifed date of the files no longer matches?

rsync has a lot of command line options. By default, it will check each file's modified timestamp and file size, and if both match, it will assume that that file is identical at the source and destination, and will not transfer that file again. Generally, moving or renaming a file does not cause the modified timestamp to be updated. So, if you move the file in the same way on both drives, the modified timestamp should not have changed, and the file size will not have changed, so you should be able to continue to use your normal rsync process without all of the files being re-written.
However, if your process does require you to write to the files, and the modification times no longer match, you can specify the -c flag to tell rsync to use a checksum instead. rsync will perform a checksum on each side and compare those checksums, instead of comparing the timestamp and filesize. Files will be skipped only if the checksum matches.

-c, --checksum
This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer. Without this option, rsync uses a
lqquick checkrq that (by default) checks if each file's size and time
of last modification match between the sender and receiver. This
option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that
has a matching size. Generating the checksums means that both sides
will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the
transfer (and this is prior to any reading that will be done to
transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly.


Using the -c option may not speed things up much when the source and destination disks are on the same computer, because calculating the checksums requires reading both the entire source and destination files to calculate their checksums. This may be a bit faster than an unnecessary copy, but only because it's reading rather than writing to the destination disk. And if it discovers a mismatch, it'll be much slower, because it'll read both files, discover the mismatch, then re-read the entire source and write the destination.

When rsync copies a file to the destination server, it does not change
the timestamp on the file that it is copying. So when you run the next
rsync it compares the date timestamps correctly.
In all cases, and depending on your backup method, the backup files
should always have the same timestamp as the source files, or slightly
newer.
Rsync prevents a newer file from being overwritten by an older file.
If you are syncing and the target's date is newer, you should get
the message "[file] is newer". Even if the timestamps are slightly
different, which can happen while copying between different
file-system formats, the backup files will not be overwritten
as long as they have the same name and the same size and the same
or newer timestamp.
